# Google Analytics API get individual property visits

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-analytics

I use Analytics management API v3 to get the list of the properties of an account via `gapi.client.analytics.management.webproperties.list`.

Every property returns ID, like this `UA-1234567-3`.

How can I use this ID to get a single property website's visits?

I've searched the query explorer, but didn't find solution for this, not sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data can be queried through views, not properties so you need to get `profileId` (the ID of view): https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/get

Then you can query that view like this:

```
  gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'metrics': 'ga:sessions'
  })
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-js

Answer (score 0):

I've found that each property returns field `defaultProfileId` which I didn't see before.
It can be used to parse property's data like this:

```
gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
      'ids': 'ga:' + defaultProfileId,
      'start-date': '2020-04-04',
      'end-date': 'today',
      'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
      'dimensions': 'ga:date'
    }).then(function(handleResults);
```